# EC2 IP works but URL gets ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I just launched a new EC2 instance for a project but used an existing security group that allows the needed inbound ports including HTML at 80.  I created an Elastic IP and associated with the new instance.  The Elastic IP works and you can see it at 54.148.175.72.  Lastly, I am using NGinX for the first time.  I do not think this is the issue as the IP works.  But it could be.

The URL is hosted at GoDaddy and updated the DNS records to point the A record to the Elastic IP and set the TTL to 600 seconds.  I did this 3 hours ago.

When I use the domain, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Chrome.  Get an error on a couple browsers.  Not sure what the issue is or WHERE it is.  Is this a problem with the DNS settings or the EC2 configuration.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does your machine resolve the DNS name to the same IP?

Comment: what's the URL you're hitting?  Hitting the IP address with curl returns a 200, so like @jarmod said, does your machine resolve the FQDN to the IP?

Answer (score 0):

Fallow the below steps to add new dns name configuration file

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/example.com
```

and then add below virtual host for your domain name

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/test.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test.com ;

        location / {

        }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-availible/example.com`.  I copied the example.com to the site.com I am using and configured using a tutorial.  I have all you have above in that file plus some other detail in the example.com file that was copied.

Comment: i mean you missed to add your DNS name in configuration file

Comment: or try to run this command `netstat -anp | grep LIST | grep  '80' `
if 80 is not open for listening  then run this command `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Are you talking about the `server_name example.com www.example.com` directive?  I configured that line.

Comment: from netstat: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18231/nginx -g daem`

Comment: okay then run

              `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

                       `service iptables save` and then restart tables 

         `service iptables restart`

then restart nginx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180314/discussion-between-sachin-ur-and-jason).

Comment: @sachin_ur you appear to be leading a wild goose chase, here.  If accessing the site by IP address works, there is nothing anywhere on the server that would lead to the domain name returning `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.